# Do App Names with Special Characters Effect their Visibility in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I plan to release an app with an accent at the end. This would be my first iPhone app in the app store so I'm sort of new to this. Do special characters in its title the hinder the chances of my app being discovered in the app store? Say for instance if I had an app by the name of *música*. If the user searches for *musica* (without the accent mark) will it return my app in the search results?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine. Apple will do a number of things to your App's name to prepare it for search matching, including the following:

> - accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)